# dont know why adding extra parameter 'undefined' in api url on AWS ec2?

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, ecmascript-6

In CONSTANTS.API_URL='"http://52.220.223.145'". `${CONSTANTS.API_URL}/api/template/list` this is what i am binding API URL in vue-js front end. when API called rom vue-js i am  getting this URL `http://52.220.223.145/undefined/api/task/list`. in this URL automatically adding extra parameters ***undefined***. I don't know what is wrong on ec2 server. when i am running on local it works fine.

```
http.post(`${CONSTANTS.API_URL}/api/template/list`, this.searchObj)
    .then((result) => {
      this.templates = result.rows
      this.searchObj = {}
      this.getTotalPages(result)
      console.log('template list', result)
    })
    .catch((httpException) => {
      console.log(httpException)
      return Utils.notify(httpException.message, 'error')
    })
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for how you make the API call

Comment: I added code above please check.

Comment: which `http` library are you using and from where are you making the call... browser / node (isomorphic stuff, etc.)

Comment: fetch-bb npm library

Comment: when application run. its called api from front-end browser

Comment: ah, I don't see any real problem with the code and information that you have pasted... maybe you try debugging / break-on the XHR request and see the stack-trace to find out more... if you are using Chrome [check this link](http://blittle.github.io/chrome-dev-tools/network/xhr-breakpoints.html)

Answer (score 1):

Shrikant,

If you http://52.220.223.145/undefined/api/task/list getting this from your code :

```
  `${CONSTANTS.API_URL}/api/template/list`
```

Then ${CONSTANTS.API_URL} must be returning with some undefined value.
Please check what is there within ${CONSTANTS.API_URL}.

Comment: Then there should be no issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `dev.env.js` file i set the api host to `http://52.220.223.145`, but when i move to stage on ec2 aws i forgot to add api host `http://52.220.223.145` in `prod.env.js`